# Backbone js event after load

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a div:

```
<div class = "desc"></div>
```

this div is in a template that a backbone view loads.

Here's the Backbone View:
      DetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {.....});

I want when the template loads, to call the following jquery function:

How can I do that?

```
 $('#desc').expander({
     slicePoint: 50,
     expandText: 'Click Here to Read More',
     userCollapseText: 'Hide Text'
 });
```

It is from the expander jquery plugin.

Comment: Show us the code for you Backbone view.

Comment: Use underscores _.defer() method in the render.

Answer (score 6):

you could do something like:

```
... Rest of View...

render: function() {
    // do your normal render stuff
    this.afterRender();
},

afterRender: function() {
    // do the stuff you want to do after the template is rendered
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do something like that:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.once('renderEvent', function () {
        // that will be executed just once after the view has been rendered
    });
},

render: function () {
    // display html
    // ...
    this.trigger('renderEvent');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you included your JS files in the header ? or in footer section.   This is one common issue happens during implementation .